# GridDB- How to display actual records in ubunto gridDB shell

Tags: sql, ubuntu, wsl-2, griddb

I have created a table and I want to return the inserted rows in gridDB shell.

When I try to get records using this query:

`select email from users where id = 1`

The above query returns `1 results. (5 ms)` but I want to return the record in the results like in this case it should display an email in the results. Is it possible in the GridDB.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To view the query result on GridDB shell, make use of the command;

```
get
```

The get command can also be used with a number like `get 20` to get only 20 from query results.